# Set downloading file path for database backup in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want to set the downloading file path of my database backup file in SQL format in the function given below. Whenever I tried this function, the file is downloaded to the download folder on my local computer, but I want to download it to a  specified directory on my server instead:

```
function admin_database_mysql_dump($tables = '*') {
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
set_time_limit(0);

$return = '';

$modelName = $this->modelClass;

$dataSource = $this->{$modelName}->getDataSource();
$databaseName = $dataSource->getSchemaName();


// Do a short header
$return .= '-- Database: `' . $databaseName . '`' . "\n";
$return .= '-- Generation time: ' . date('D jS M Y H:i:s') . "\n\n\n";


if ($tables == '*') {
    $tables = array();
    $result = $this->{$modelName}->query('SHOW TABLES');
    foreach($result as $resultKey => $resultValue){
        $tables[] = current($resultValue['TABLE_NAMES']);
    }
} else {
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
}

// Run through all the tables
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $tableData = $this->{$modelName}->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);

    $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $table . ';';
    $createTableResult = $this->{$modelName}->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $table);
    $createTableEntry = current(current($createTableResult));
    $return .= "\n\n" . $createTableEntry['Create Table'] . ";\n\n";

    // Output the table data
    foreach($tableData as $tableDataIndex => $tableDataDetails) {

        $return .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES(';

        foreach($tableDataDetails[$table] as $dataKey => $dataValue) {

            if(is_null($dataValue)){
                $escapedDataValue = 'NULL';
            }
            else {
                // Convert the encoding
                $escapedDataValue = mb_convert_encoding( $dataValue, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" );

                // Escape any apostrophes using the datasource of the model.
                $escapedDataValue = $this->{$modelName}->getDataSource()->value($escapedDataValue);
            }

            $tableDataDetails[$table][$dataKey] = $escapedDataValue;
        }
        $return .= implode(',', $tableDataDetails[$table]);

        $return .= ");\n";
    }

    $return .= "\n\n\n";
}

// Set the default file name
$fileName = $databaseName . '-backup-' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . '.sql';

// Serve the file as a download
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('Content-Type: text/x-sql');
$this->response->download($fileName);
$this->response->body($return);
}
```

Comment: you want it to be on server itself ?

Comment: i just want to change the downloading location to my other directory instead of download folder(default)

Comment: location of saving a file from a browser is based on browser itself,

Comment: i want to download backup file in my App->webroot   directory on server.

Comment: Check `http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the very bottom of your `admin_database_mysql_dump` function:

```
file_put_contents ( ROOT.'/app/webroot/sql/' . $fileName , $return );
```

This will download the .sql file to a folder `sql` in your `app/webroot` directory.

However this will also still download a copy to your local computer as well. If you do not want to do this simply remove the following lines:

```
$this->response->download($fileName);
$this->response->body($return);
```

...and add a new line to redirect after the file is generated. Something similar to:

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

So altogether the bottom of your revised function should look like this:

```
// Set the default file name
$fileName = $databaseName . '-backup-' . date('Y-m-d_H-i-s') . '.sql';

// Serve the file as a download
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type('Content-Type: text/x-sql');

//these two lines should be removed
// $this->response->download($fileName);
// $this->response->body($return);

//add this to write the file to server
file_put_contents ( ROOT.'/app/tmp/' . $fileName , $return );

//add this to redirect the browser to the referer
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```